# Divide the elements of a given string

Tags: c#, list

I should divide the elements into several small substrings with **equal length**. The **count of the substrings should be equal to the given partitions**. If the string cannot be **exactly divided** into the given partitions, I must **make all partitions except the last with equal lengths**, and make the **last one – the longest**.

I've tried to make the first part, but it's not working in all cases. Can you show me a way but if it's possible with for-loops, etc.?

For example:
{abcd}, 3 partitions -> {a, b, cd}; {qrstuvwxyz}, 5 partitions -> {qr st uv wx yz}

```
private static List<string> Divide(List<string> input, int index, int partitions)
{
        string stringToDivide = input[index];
        input.RemoveAt(index);
        string add = "";

        if (stringToDivide.Length % partitions == 0)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < stringToDivide.Length; i++)
            {
                add += stringToDivide[i] + " ";
            }

            input.Insert(index, add.Trim());
        }
        else
        {

        }
        return input;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(' ', input));
}
```

Comment: Can you give some test cases (expected inputs and outputs)?

Comment: why is the input a list, shouldn't the input be a string?

Comment: @WaiHaLee, yes I can. {abcd}, 3 partitions -> {a, b, cd}; {qrstuvwxyz}, 5 partitions -> {qr st uv wx yz}

Comment: >and the last one – should be the longest.
but not >= 2 symbols longer?

Comment: @Hogan, this is a part of a problem which I am solving, and it's more accurate to use lists.

Comment: @ingvar, I don't understand your question. I should divide the elements into several small substrings with equal length. The count of the substrings should be equal to the given partitions. If the string cannot be exactly divided into the given partitions, I must make all partitions except the last with equal lengths, and make the last one – the longest.

Comment: You have not clearly described the problem, and you're the one asking strangers for help.  **Please give some examples of expected inputs and outputs, and ask a more clear question**.  This is not a site for doing your homework for you.

Comment: @EricLippert, I've added some examples. This isn't my homework. Why do you treat new users like a scumbag? I'm a new programmer, and I am trying to learn.

Comment: No one is treating you poorly; you're asking a confusing question and we're trying to help you by getting you to clarify the question; that will get you a better solution and get it to you faster. **Asking clear questions is a vital skill for new programmers to learn.** Today would be a great day to learn it.  **Help us help you**.

Comment: For example, you say you've "added some examples".  You have not.  You've added some vague, confusing text with a lot of letters in it.  **Add a test case that we can run**.  We're *programmers*. Give us a *program*, not some weird syntax that is not legal C# that you just made up that we then have to try to understand.

Comment: @Eric Lippert, as you see, I added some examples. I don't know what is still confusing. I tried to explain at the comments above.

Comment: A proper example would be something like `var result = Divide(new List<string>() { "foo", "bar" }, 2, 3); Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result);` and then say what the expected output string is. **That's a program fragment that we could actually run, look at in the debugger, and so on**.  That is *clear*.  Again, **help us help you**. Don't make us do work to help you; you do **as much work as you can to help us get you the solution as quickly as possible**.

Comment: Or, another way you could make the question more clear.  You said "it is not working in all cases".  **That tells us nothing**.  We already know it is not working in all cases; if it were working in all cases, you would not be asking the question. **Tell us what works and what doesn't by -- again -- writing a series of test cases that show the inputs, the expected outputs, and the actual outputs**. Give examples of cases that succeed and cases that fail. **That will help us understand where the problem is**.

Comment: Remember, your goal here as a beginner programmer is *learn how to program*. Asking other people to do your work for you will not make you successful as a programmer. **Organizing your work, writing test cases, and clearly describing problems is a big part of professional programming**, so practice that skill today.

Comment: @EricLippert, I appreciate that you explain to me all these things. I will definitely use them in my next post. Greetings, Kaloyan

Comment: Hi Kaloyan, something to remember for next time, my question was valid given what you had written.  You describe taking a string and doing an operation on it, in fact you want the function to take an array, select an element and do an operation on that element.  I know this is subtle and seems simple and obvious (since it was the first few lines of you code), but as someone who is trying to help this kind of minor point makes it much harder to understand what you need.  That is why I asked the question I did.   My question is still valid even with your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
private static List<string> Divide(List<string> input, int index, int partitions)
{
    var stringToDivide = input[index];
    input.RemoveAt(index);

    var stringToAdd = "";
    var partitionLength = stringToDivide.Length / partitions;

    for (int i = 0, partitionNum = 0; i < stringToDivide.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i % partitionLength == 0 && partitionNum != partitions)  // skip space in last part
        {
            if (i > 0) // do not add leading space
            {
                stringToAdd += " ";
            }

            partitionNum++;
        }

        stringToAdd += stringToDivide[i];
    }

    input.Insert(index, stringToAdd);

    return input;
}
```

This code adds spaces each `partitionLength`, but skips space for last string. Note that for long strings it's better to use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

`stringToDivide.Length % partitions` is the number of characters left over after dividing into `partitions` number of partitions.

`stringToDivide.Length / partitions` is the number of characters that should be in each partition except the last, which should have the left-over characters appended to it.

So just take the first `partitions` number of `stringToDivide.Length / partitions` length chunks, and append what's left over to the last chunk.

When the string is evenly divisible, `stringToDivide.Length % partitions` is zero, so it's not a special case.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score -1):

```
 public static List<string> DivideIntoPartitions(string stringToDivide, int partitions)
        {
            var parts = new List<string>(partitions);
            var len = stringToDivide.Length;

            if (len < partitions)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("partitions should be less than length");
            }

            if (len % partitions == 0)
            {
                var eachSubstrLength = len / partitions;

                for (int i = 0; i < stringToDivide.Length; i += eachSubstrLength)
                {
                    parts.Add(stringToDivide.Substring(i, eachSubstrLength));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var nextDivisibleNumber = len + (partitions - (len % partitions));
                var lengthOfLastSubstr = nextDivisibleNumber / partitions;
                var lastItem = stringToDivide.Substring((len - lengthOfLastSubstr));
                stringToDivide = stringToDivide.Remove((len - lengthOfLastSubstr));

                var chunksize = stringToDivide.Length / (partitions - 1);

                for (int i = 0; i < stringToDivide.Length; i += chunksize)
                {
                    parts.Add(stringToDivide.Substring(i, chunksize));
                }
                parts.Add(lastItem);

            }
            return parts;

        }

 var result = DivideIntoPartitions("qrstuvwxyz", 3);
```